# Semantic UI - Avoid repeat links (SEO trouble) using responsive classes

Tags: hyperlink, responsive-design, seo, duplicates, semantic-ui

I'm developing a web site, and I'm using [SemanticUI](http://semantic-ui.com/). 
I prepared this example to explain the problem:

```
<header>
    <div class="ui vertical large menu red item page fluid grid">
        <div class="mobile only row">
            <div class="ui icon dropdown fluid center align massive button">
                <i class="content icon"></i>
                Menú
                <div class="ui vertical menu">
                    <a class="item" href="#"> Home </a> <!-- ¡¡Repeted link!! -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui six menu red item fluid grid">
        <div class="tablet only row">
            <img src="http://goo.gl/ToQcwM" width="20px"/>
            <a class="item" href="#"> Home </a> <!-- ¡¡Repeted link!! -->
        </div>

        <div class="computer only row">
            <img src="http://goo.gl/ljDWQ7" width="20px"/>
            <a class="item" href="#"> Home </a> <!-- ¡¡Repeted link!! -->
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

The trouble (SEO problem) is that I have to duplicate the three links above and of course, I don't want to do it. Actually, the site is build with PHP and I don't really doubled code (it's an include in PHP).

I prepared also a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7sLfnva3/2/). To test it, you have to redimension the window in order to see the effects.

Of course, this is not the real situation. You can see the [real web](http://www.peluqueriapilarsilvan.com/) if you want.

So, anyone with a solution? best practices about this?

PD: Sorry for my english! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I just maintain one div with all links not repeated and then with CSS style that menu for mobiles.